# Decorator Design Pattern - Example

Tags: c#, design-patterns, decorator

I am trying to understand Decorator Design Pattern.

Wonder what is the best way to decorate fields values in below example?

Am I using decorator pattern correctly? If not how can I improve it?

```
public class Fields
{
   string InvoiceNumber {get;set;}
   DateTime InvoiceDate {get;set;}
   DateTime DueDate {get;set;}
   string ReferenceNumber {get;set;}
   string OrganisationNumber {get;set;}
}



Fields fields = new Fields();
fields.InvoiceNumber = "1234";

Decorator1 decorator1 = new Decorator1(fields);
decorator1.Decorate(fields.InvoiceNumber);

Console.Write(fields.InvoiceNumber); //it changes InvoiceNumber to 1234++

Decorator2 decorator2 = new Decorator2(fields);
decorator2.Decorate(fields.InvoiceNumber); 

Console.Write(fields.InvoiceNumber); //it changes InvoiceNumber to 1234--
```

Comment: That's not exactly how a Decorator is supposed to work. What information about the pattern did you base this on?

Comment: @Fildor It is based on borrow book example. May be I am wrong but need help to use decorator pattern to change field values based on decorator. https://www.dofactory.com/net/decorator-design-pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My take on a similar decorator pattern would be something like this:

```
public interface IFields
{
    string InvoiceNumber {get;set;}
}

public class Fields : IFields
{
   string InvoiceNumber {get;set;}
   // Let's dumb it down to one Field for brevity
}

public class FieldsPlusDecorator : IFields
{
    public static IFields Decorate(IFields decoratee) => new FieldsPlusDecorator (decoratee);
    
    private readonly IFields _subject:
    private FieldsPlusDecorator (IFields subject) => _subject = subject;
    
    public string InvoiceNumber
    {
       get { return $"{subject.InvoiceNumber}++"; }
       set { throw new NotSupportedException(); } // Again: For Brevity, maybe just write-through ...
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
IFields myFields = new Fields(){ InvoiceNumber = "1234" };
Console.WriteLine(myFields.InvoiceNumber); // 1234

myFields = FieldsPlusDecorator.Decorate(myFields);
Console.WriteLine(myFields.InvoiceNumber); // 1234++
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your use case. I would implement some field processors that modify the InvoiceNumber string property. In my case, I like to return new objects and not change the current ones. Anyway, this is not a decorator pattern, and the implementation I suggest depends on the actual functionality.

```
var fields = new Fields { InvoiceNumber = "1234" };

var plus = new PlusInvoiceNumberProcessor();
var fieldsPlus = plus.Process(fields);

Console.WriteLine(fieldsPlus.InvoiceNumber); //it changes InvoiceNumber to 1234++

var minus = new MinusInvoiceNumberProcessor();
var fieldsMinus = minus.Process(fields);

Console.Write(fieldsMinus.InvoiceNumber); //it changes InvoiceNumber to 1234--

public record Fields
{
    // ...
}

public interface IInvoiceNumberProcessor
{
    Fields Process(Fields fields);
}

public class PlusInvoiceNumberProcessor : IInvoiceNumberProcessor
{
    public Fields Process(Fields fields)
        => fields with { InvoiceNumber = $"{fields.InvoiceNumber}++" };
}

public class MinusInvoiceNumberProcessor : IInvoiceNumberProcessor
{
    public Fields Process(Fields fields)
        => fields with { InvoiceNumber = $"{fields.InvoiceNumber}--" };
}
```